# JSON data is changing between $http.post and $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, get

I am having a hard time figuring out what the problem is. I have a JSON file that gets $http.post to the my work's server. I then call a $http.get to retrieve the JSON file and the retrieved JSON file is missing attributes, and it gets replaced by a different one. This is an angularJS app.

Here is the JSON before the POST [JSON before POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3n5I.png)

and here is the JSON snippet after the GET
[JSON after GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OfCr.png)

As you can see through the pictures above, the JSON data element "Schedules":{data here} gets removed and changed to "Schedule": null

Here is the code I am using to post and get

GET:

```
return $http.get(Commonsvc.context.serviceUrl + '\\api\\project\\' + $routeParams.projectId).success(function(result){
           doc = result;
           //console.log('object after import: '+JSON.stringify(doc));
       });
```

POST:

```
$http.post(Commonsvc.context.serviceUrl + '\\api\\project', $scope.projectModel).then(function(result){
    console.log('Project Model object AFTER posting: '+JSON.stringify($scope.projectModel));
});
```

I have no clue why this is happening. I appreciate everyone's time in advanced.

**EDIT**: I figured out what was going on, it was a dumb mistake on my part, I forgot to update the class definition that the JSON was being defined against. So, yes it was a server side error...there goes many hours of scratching my head XD

Cheers,

A

Comment: looks like it's a server side issue, look at the response in your browsers dev tools to confirm what is actually been returned from the server

Comment: in one case you're logging the result of the ajax request, in the other you're logging something from scope..

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the dev world. But does it make a difference if I'm logging the ajax request for the post, and something from scope in the get? In the get I am simply passing the URL. Post is getting fed the $scope project model data. @KevinB

Comment: well, your code as is doesn't do anything with the result data on the POST request. surely that isn't your intent.